# iOS Matrix and Vector Operations

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, webgl

I am in the process of converting a Web GL application into iOS.

The web gl version of the app uses the gl-matrix package (https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix) to perform matrix and vector operations.

I was wondering what the equivalent package would be in iOS?

For instance one of the lines of code in the javascript application uses the line:

```
return new glMatrixArrayType([x * sin2, y * sin2, z * sin2, Math.cos(a2)]);
```

In iOS what should I use instead of glMatrixArrayType.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean iOS 5+, the equivalent is [GLKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/_index.html). Prior to that you were on your own as far as the OS was concerned.

It doesn't have a 2x2 matrix so the equivalent to that line of code would be (well, probably, unless I've got my rows and columns transposed — I don't know gl-matrix):

```
return GLKMatrix3Make(
          x * sin2, y * sin2, 0.0f,
          z*sin2,   cos(a2),  0.0f, 
          0.0f,     0.0f,     1.0f);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am developing for iOS so will use this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

iOS's matrix and vector library is called **vecLib**. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/Reference/reference.html). I'm unfamiliar with it, however, so I wouldn't know the exact equivalent of `glMatrixArrayType` in vecLib, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, Yes your answer is what I was looking for, I can now begin to develop in the right direction

Comment: Tommy K's answer below is a better answer than this one if you are targeting iOS 5+. GLKit is a much newer framework than vecLib and is likely much easier to use.